# Сортировка текcтового файла и вывод результата сортировки в новый файл C#

Tags: c#

Есть текстовый файл с именами , кличками и фамилиями. Каждое имя, фамилия, отчество начинаются с новой строки. Нужно создать новый текстовый файл где все эти люди должны быть отсортированны по имени или по фамилии или по отчеству или по кличке. Притом у некоторых людей могут быть не только одна кличка. Пример "Вася Корж Кисель Петров
\t" Андрей Хмурый Иванов ". При сортировке по фамилии на первой строке нового текстового файла должен быть Андрей затем Вася. При этом порядок слов в строке не должен менаться

```
Console.WriteLine("Choose sorting method of customers: 1. for Last name 2. for first given name");

string inFile = @"/unsort-customers.txt";

string outFile = @"/sort-costumers.txt";

string booferFile =@"/boofer.txt" ;

var contents = File.ReadAllLines(inFile);

foreach (var item in contents)
{
    string[] names = item.Split(' ');
    string name = names.First();
    string surname = names.Last();
    string klichka1 = names[1];
    string klichka = names[2];


    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(booferFile, true))
    {
        if (chooseButton == "1")
        {
            file.WriteLine((name + " " + surname).Trim());
        }
        else if (chooseButton == "2")
        {
            file.WriteLine((klichka1 + " " + name + " " 
surname).Trim());
        }
        else if (chooseButton != "1" || chooseButton != "2" ) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Формат строки (данных с файла, где клички, имена и др.) в вопрос добавьте! По сути здесь простой `File.ReadAllLines(...)` / `File.WriteAllLines(...)` для чтения и записи, `Split()` для разбивки на имя/фамилию/кличку (все зависит от формата) и `OrderBy(x=>x....)` для сортировки. Попробуйте сами с помощью этих методов решить задачу, вам будет полезно!

Comment: Тут дело в том, что в каждой строчке разное количество слов(имя, фамилия, кличка) и у другого (имя, фамилия, кличка1, кличка2). Как отсортировать и получить доступ именно к кличке2 или кличке1 если они посередине массива получаются

Comment: Повторю еще раз. Стоит добавить в сам вопрос (кнопка править под ним) все возможные варианты строки. Это поможет другим участникам лучше понять вопрос. Сейчас же у вас уже висит голос за закрытие по причине "непонятна суть вопроса", вы же не хотите что бы вопрос закрыли, так? Тогда пожалуйста, добавьте как можно больше информации (входные, выходные данные; ваши попытки и др.)!

Comment: Исправил. И вставил код

Answer (score 1):

Наперед: код писать умышленно не буду.

Код слишком простой и должен быть реализован тобой самим. Но распишу алгоритм.

1. Создай класс `Human` который отвечает за человека. (имя, фамилия, кличка1, кличка2, кличка3 и что там еще у тебя может быть). В этом же классе должен быть метод заполнения со строки ( `FromString(string str)`) и метод преобразования инстанса в строку -- переопределенный `ToString()`
2. построчно считай файл генеря список людей `List<Human>`
3. При помощи LINQ отсортируй список по нужной проперти `OrderBy(x=>x....)`
4. Сохрани список в файл используя Stream и AppendLine метод используя все тот же метод ToString() у каждого из людей

   ```
   public FromString(string str)
   {
       string[] arr = str.Split(' ');

       FirstName = GetFromIndexIfExist(arr, 0); //то есть положение слова в строке из оригинального файла
       LastName = GetFromIndexIfExist(arr, 1);
       FictionName1 = GetFromIndexIfExist(arr, 2);
       FictionName2 = GetFromIndexIfExist(arr, 3);
       FictionName3 = GetFromIndexIfExist(arr, 4);
   }

   public override string ToString() =>
       $"{FirstName} {LastName} {FictionName1} {FictionName2} {FictionName3}"; 
       //то есть та последовательность, которая у тебя в оригинале файла

   private string GetFromIndexIfExist(string[] arr, index) =>
       (arr.Count() >= index) ? arr[index] : string.Empty;
   ```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Чувствуется рука мастера. А можно по подробнее чуточки про метод заполнения со строки(или реализовать это в конструкторе класса) и про метод преобразования синтаксиса.

Comment: метод преобразования инстанса а не синтаксиса. Дописал.

Comment: До мастера мне пока что далеко) Я он задал вопрос один на SO, мне ответили и я нихрена не понимаю :D Наверное день потрачу что бы понять что же мне ответили :D А такие задачи как эта решаются вообще элементарно. Скоро научишся)

Comment: @Andrew, если я правильно понял вопрос, то ваше решение будет работать в случае сортировки по имени или фамилии. Кличек же может быть несколько. таким образом при формировании списка для последующей сортировки по кличкам, нужно: либо переопределять метод для сравнения, либо дублировать сущности по всем кличкам, сортировать и избавляться от дубликатов

Comment: да, я не подумал что кличка1 и кличка2 это одна сущность... Но в то же время автором не указано ожидаемое поведение при сортировке по кличке.  В принципе, можно все клички сохранять в `List<string>` и сортировать еще на стадии инициализации обьекта через `FromString(str)`. В таком случае достаточно будет отсортировать по нулевому элементу клички `OrderBy(x=>x.FictionName[0])`

Comment: List<Human> HumanList = new List<Human>();

            Human user = new Human();

            foreach (var item in contents)
            {
                    user.FromString(item);

                    HumanList.Add(user);

            } Так HumanList имеет лишь последнее значение. Не пойму почему

Comment: @Andrew, на момент создания экземпляра класса мы еще не знаем по какому принципу будет проходить сортировка ( поля, направление). а если потребуется несколько списков с различными сортировками ? в целом, на мой взгляд, алгоритм не совсем уж тривиальный, с изюминкой ;)

Comment: Не могу понять как динамически создавать новый класс Human при каждом проходе Foreach ( который считывает одну строку текста)

Comment: ну если важно оставлять оригинальную сортировку кличек, то тогда вложенный LINQ запрос использовать при сортировке по кличке. Тоже все достаточно тривиально.

Comment: перенеси обьявление нового хьюмана внутрь форича. А то ты добавляешь один и тот же обьект N раз

Comment: Точно. Работает. Спасибки. Вечно благодарен. Пишу дальше

Comment: а еще можно вообще сделать вот так: http://prntscr.com/maz0tz должно сработать ;) Или добавить инициализацию со строки сразу вызовом этого метода -- будет более читабельно.  http://prntscr.com/maz2ip

Comment: var orderedList = HumanList.OrderBy(user => user.LastName).ToList();
            foreach (var items in orderedList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(items);
            } Не сортирует почему-то

Comment: не может быть :) Внимательно перепроверь.

Comment: Рfботает только сортировка по первому имени и  первой кличке. Проверяю метод FromString()

Answer (score 0):

все же добавлю свой вариант

```
 // опускаем построчное чтение файла (отчества тут тоже нет :))
        var lines = new List<string> {
            "Вася Пупкин Васёк Квас",
            "Архимед Эвриков Эврик"
        };


        var orderedList = lines
            .Select(line =>
            {
                // далее нет необходимых проверок, хотя по хорошему они должны быть:
                // - существование нужного индекса
                // - очистка результатов

                var temp = line.Split(' ');
                var otherNames = temp.Skip(2).ToList();    

                return new
                {
                    InitialStr = line,
                    FirstName = temp[0],
                    LastName = temp[1],
                    OtherNames = otherNames,
                    // выбираем кличку прямой сортировкой
                    ONameAsc = otherNames.OrderBy(n => n).FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty,
                    // выбираем кличку обратной сортировкой
                    ONameDesc = otherNames.OrderByDescending(n => n).FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty
                };
            })
            //.OrderBy(it => it.LastName)
            //.OrderByDescending(it => it.FirstName)
            //.OrderBy(it => it.ONameAsc)
            .OrderByDescending(it => it.ONameDesc)
            .Select(it=> it.InitialStr)
            .ToList();

        // осталось записать результат в файл
```

Answer (score -1):

Проще всего, наверное, вначале преобразовать текстовый файл в файл базы данных. Например,если, каждая запись начинается с новой строки, считать файл построчно, потом каждую строку распарсить, а результат добавить в БД.
После этого вам будет доступна вся мощь СУБД. Обратное преобразование (БД-файл) производится элементарно...

Comment: Какую БД посоветуете?

Comment: Это как из гранатомета по тараканам. БД в даной задаче -- явное излишество. При чем независимо от БД.

Comment: MySQl  используйте